# How to iterate through a list of arrays using thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I'm trying to populate a table in my template with a list of object arrays

```
List<Object[]> list
```

Every object array of this list has a fixed length and it's the same for all.

I need something like this

```html
<table>
    <tr th:each="obArr:${list}">
        <td th:text="${obArr[0]}"></td>
        <td th:text="${obArr[1]}"></td>
        <td th:text="${obArr[2]}"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is this possible using thymeleaf, or should I try a different approach?

Comment: Yeah, that's possible... what is the problem?  I don't see anything wrong with what you have there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

You can find some helpful examples here:
http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#listing-seed-starter-data